# Wireless focus for the Ronin-M

Tags: video, focus, gear

I've recently purchased a Ronin-M and have been shooting a good bit of run-n-gun projects with it. But the biggest limitation I've found with it is focusing, so I've started looking around for wireless focus systems, but the best deal that I can find is more than the gimbal itself (the RedRock MicroRemote). Does anyone know of any (-$1000) system for one-man focusing on a small gimbal?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of mount your camera has. This is a good solution for the A7S or A7R and was recently shown at NAB: The Aputure DEC. They also have one for MFT.

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?ci=23192&N=3989452947&mnp=0&mxp=1000

And this should be available soon!

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1608311032/lenzhound-wireless-lens-motor-control-system/

Comment: That's a really neat deal, I'm using Nikon though...I'll keep an eye out for the lenshound to be released.